# Make current menu item clickable in the category blog

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, category-blog

Hello I am using this code:

```
<?php
    $active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
    echo $active->title;
?>
```

To show the current menu item title, but how can I make it linkable? So its a link and I can click it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the link, you can simply use `$active->link`.

So based on your code, you can use the following:

```
$active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
$title  = $active->title;
$url    = JRoute::_($active->link);

echo '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a>';
```

Comment: works like a charm. simple and easy. thank you very much sir!

Comment: @Peter - Glad it helped :)